# i want to scroll content into scroll view on button click

Tags: ios, iphone

I have added these code to scroll content into scroll view but instead of content my scroll view fram is moving from right to left and respectivelly.
my code is here..
    [image: in this image there are two buttons both side of scroll view]

```
-(IBAction)leftbtnclick:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"left clicked");
    CGRect basketTopFrame = nameContainerScrollView.frame;
    basketTopFrame.origin.x = 115;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{ nameContainerScrollView.frame = basketTopFrame; } completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];


}

-(IBAction)rightbtnclick:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"right clicked");
    CGRect napkinBottomFrame = nameContainerScrollView.frame;
    napkinBottomFrame.origin.x = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{ nameContainerScrollView.frame = napkinBottomFrame; } completion:^(BOOL finished){/*done*/}];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll `scrollView` to particular position/offset by this line of code

```
[addFeedsScroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 262, addFeedsScroll.frame.size.width, addFeedsScroll.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

**NOTE:-** addFeedsScroll is `UIScrollView`.